# bootstrap thumbnails in horizontal scrolls

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

hi I'm trying tom make the bootstrap thumbnails fit in a Div that has a horizontal scroll. The problem I'm getting is that they are collapsing beneath it rather then offsetting as can be see in the image. Anyone know how i can fix this? the code below is the one I'm using.

```
<div class="container">
    <h1 style="color:white">Merchandise</h1>
    <div style="overflow-x: scroll;width:100%;">
    <?php 
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($Merchval)) 
        {
             echo '<div style="float:left;width:200px;display: block;">
                    <div class="thumbnail " style="margin-right:5px;margin-left:5px;">
                        <img src="assets/Merch/'.$row[1].''.$row[2].'" alt="'.$row[1].'">
                        <div class="caption">
                            <h3>'.$row[0].'</h3>
                            <h7>'.$row[3].'</h7>
                            <p>€'.$row[4].'</p>
                            <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Button</a> 
                        </div>
                     </div>
                    </div>';
        }
    ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: which html version have `<h7></h7>` ?

Comment: Get rid of the PHP and include the HTML output. This is not a PHP question.

Comment: i included php in case it was a problem from that part of the code

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine. There must be something else causing the problem. Do you have a CSS setting for `.container`?

```css
.container {
  background: darkgray;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1 style="color:white">Merchandise</h1>
  <div style="overflow-x: scroll;width:100%;">
  
    <div style="float:left;width:200px;  display: block;">
      <div class="thumbnail " style="margin-right:5px;margin-left:5px;">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/100" alt="">
        <div class="caption">
          <h3>Test</h3>
          <h7>Test</h7>
          <p>€200</p>
          <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Button</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div style="float:left;width:200px;  display: block;">
      <div class="thumbnail " style="margin-right:5px;margin-left:5px;">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/100" alt="">
        <div class="caption">
          <h3>Test</h3>
          <h7>Test</h7>
          <p>€200</p>
          <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Button</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hi thanks for responding please see the image that i have included in the question to get a better understanding of what my problem is

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it to work this is the code now :

```html
<div class="container">
     <h1 style="color:white">Merchandise</h1>  
            <div style="overflow-x: scroll;width:100%;    white-space: nowrap;">
                                 <?php 
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($Merchval)) {
        echo '<div style="width:200px;display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;"><div class="thumbnail " style="margin-right:5px;margin-left:5px;">
                          <img src="assets/Merch/'.$row[1].''.$row[2].'" alt="'.$row[1].'">
                          <div class="caption">
                            <h3>'.$row[0].'</h3>
                            <h7>'.$row[3].'</h7>
                            <p>€'.$row[4].'</p>
                            <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Button</a> 
                          </div>
                        </div> </div>';
   }
                        ?>
          </div>
        </div>
```